# Install a .deb package with dpkg-deb without creating the usr folder

Tags: 20.04, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I am installing a debian package using `dpkg-deb` on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (64-bit). I want to install it in a specific directory, called `software`. Inside this directory I have already the `bin`, the `share`, the `include`, the `lib` directories.

Here's how I tried to install the package:

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4_7.74.0-1.3+b1_amd64.deb
dpkg-deb -x libcurl4_7.74.0-1.3+b1_amd64.deb /gpfs/software
```

The `/gpfs/software` directory is the one where I want to install it. The result of this operation is an error-less installation. However, it creates a directory named `usr` contained inside the `software` directory. Inside `usr`, you'll find `lib` and `share` which I already have inside `software. Like this:

```
.
└── software
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    ├── share
    │   └── man
    └── usr
        ├── lib
        └── share
```

My question is: how can I tell `dpkg-deb` to put the contents of `software/usr/lib` and of `software/usr/share` inside `software/lib` and `software/share`?

Comment: You haven't provided any OS & release, however downloading and install packages built for Debian on a Ubuntu system, can be like asking for problems. You also highlight many version of python that aren't standard versions used by on-topic releases.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: You must edit the package's file structure. The file paths are hard-coded in the package's data.tar.xz archive. This is not a trivial task for beginner. Note that this means dpkg will promptly start complaining that the package has been (correctly) tampered with, that you likely cannot upgrade the package (the upgrade will change all the file paths back to normal), and that if you lose that altered package, you won't be able to use dpkg to uninstall the altered package software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot tell that. `dpkg-deb` installs the `.deb` package according to how it is packaged. It is the packager of the `.deb` package that decides how files are arranged. You only can decide on the parent directory where it is installed (`/gpfs/software` in your example).

You would need to repackage the software yourself in a  different `.deb` package in order to change this.